# Why I cant get the whole content of a website?

Tags: python, python-requests

First of all, sorry for my bad English. I want to make my one Data science project and I had the idea to download the daily substitution plan.

I managed to make it login to the website dsbmobile.de, but now, when I want to get the content of the website with a request command, the python script returns only a part of the whole thing.

If I inspect the website with chrome, I can see the part of the html text, which I need. So, my question. How can I get the whole content of the website?

This is my function I have writen:

```
def main(username, password):
url = "https://www.dsbmobile.de/Login.aspx"

payload = {
    '__LASTFOCUS': '',
    '__VIEWSTATE': '#VIEWSTATE',
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': 'C2EE9ABB',
    '__EVENTTARGET': '',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
    '__EVENTVALIDATION': '#EVENTVALIDATION',
    'txtUser': username,
    'txtPass': password,
    'ctl03': 'Anmelden'
}

with requests.session() as session:
    reponse = requests.post(url, data = payload)
    r = session.get(url)
    print(reponse.text)
    print(r)


with open("index.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(reponse.text)
```

And in the html text I had get, is instead of the substitution plan this:

```
<div id="content" class="content clearfix transition-3ms">
        <!-- Content -->
</div>
```

Thanks in advance,
JoJo369

Comment: You aren't showing us the whole result, but _typically_ this means that the content is generated in the browser with javascript, instead of returned by the server as part of the initial response. That said, questions that only make sense as long as a 3rd-party website's contents stay the same don't work towards our goal of building a long-lived Q&A knowledgebase.

Comment: It's probably generated by Javascript. You'll need a web driver that can run Javascript, such as Selenium.

Comment: Consider using your browser's debugger to look at what other network requests are made while this page is loaded and what their responses are after the request in question. You may be able to find an API call it makes to retrieve the data you're interested in.

Comment: First thanks for the fast answers

Comment: One question can I make with selenium a automatic bot, what runs on a server.